# Solving this particular Linear System of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Problem: $dx/dt = x + y; dy/dt = y$

My try: 
Since y is the derivative of itself, we have: $y = c_2e^t$

Now for x, let $D = d/dt$
Then we get the following:
$Dx = x + y$ and $Dy = y$

Differentiating again we get:
$D^2x = Dx + Dy$

Substituing the stuff back in we get
$(D^2 - 2D + 1)x = 0$

Solving for gives us D = 1, giving:
$x = c_1e^t$

This is where I get stuck, because x isnt finished yet, where do I go from here?

The final answer should be: $x = c_1e^t + c_2te^t$

Comment: I think you can solve it easily from $$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}-x=c_{1}e^{t}$$ because it's one order linear ODE.

Comment: Notice $(D^2-2D+1) = (D-1)^2$ and $1$ is a double root. In general, if a polynomial $P(D)$ can be factorized as $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n (D - \lambda_i)^{\eta_i}$, the special solution of $P(D)y = 0$ has the form $y(t) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n f_i(t)e^{\lambda_i t}$ where $f_i(t)$ are polynomials with degree $< \eta_i$.